# Transactional Replication does not replicate SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactional-replication

I have set up a one-to-one push trasactional replication with all articles copy properties set to `TRUE`. That's because I will need to back up the subscriber at some point with new data and restore as the primary database.

The setup is all fine except one schema issue: `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` is not transferred to subscriber when I compare the two databases on any of the articles (tables, views, etc). Is there a configuration that I am missing to have this corrected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a documented bug with the Distribution agent replacing the square brackets around the name with quotes during replication.  As a result, the quoted identifier hint is dropped so it does not throw a syntax error near the name.  The documentation mostly refers to SProcs, but it may be worth investigating. Sources below:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/sql-server-transactional-replication
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278324